# how to build an array while using toggles in angular2 in ionic2

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

i want to build an array of objects when i toggled

```
 var data = [ 
          { catId : Vegitarian,
           subcats :[
                    {
                      category : "potatoes",
                      rank : 23,
                      catId : "Vegitarian"
                    },
                    {
                     category : "tomatoes",
                     rank : 2,
                     catId : "Vegitarian"
                    }
                  ]
            },
            { catId : "Non-vegetarian",
              subcats :[
                        {
                         category : "appetizers",
                         rank : 3,
                         catId : "Non-vegetarian"
                        },
                        {
                         category : "nonveg-appitizers",
                         rank : 52,
                         catId : "Non-vegetarian"
                        }
                      ]
               }

        ]
```

### my html code

```
<div *ngFor="let cats of data">
<ion-row >
 <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="cats.checked" (ionChange)="checkCats()"></ion-toggle>
</ion-row>

<div *ngFor="let subCats of cats.subcats">
   <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="subCat.checked" (ionChange)="checkCats()"></ion-toggle>
</div>

</div>
```

My requirement is when i toggle the `cats.checked` then the below all `subcats` also have to select, when i un-select the `cats.checked` then all the `subCats` also have to un-select upto here my code is working fine but when i un-select single `subCats` the relted `cats.checked` has to unselect, if i again select the cats then related all subCats ahs to select

### here is my ts code

```
this.result=[];
      checkCats(catObj) {
    this.result = this.data.filter(cats => {
          if ((cats.checked == true) && (cats.subcats.length != 0)) {
            cats.subcats.filter(subCat => {
              subCat.checked = true
            })
            return cats
          } else if ((cats.checked == true) && (cats.subcats.length == 0)) {
            return cats
          } else if ((cats.checked == false) && (cats.subcats.length != 0)) {
             cats.subcats.filter(subCat => {
              subCat.checked = false
            }) 
          }
    })

    }
```

### what i getting as result

iam getting the whole object even if i un-selected the  `potatoes`

```
[
  {
    "catId": "vegetarian",
    "subcats": [
      {
        "subCatId": "potatoes",
        "catId": "vegetarian",
        "rank ": 23,
        "checked": true
      },
      {
        "subCatId": "tomatoes",
        "rank ": 2,
        "catId": "vegetarian",
        "checked": true
      }
     ]
   }
 ]
```

Comment: Just a quick view, but i think you have wrong filtering... you have to return the boolean: cats.subcats.filter(subCat => { return subCat.checked = true })